# Meteor getting userId in startup function

Tags: meteor

How can I get the `userId` in `Meteor.startup` function any ideas? I need it to run a loop that pings every 10 seconds but all I get is `Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.`

My code:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log(Meteor.userId());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not likely to get the `Meteor.userId()` in the `startup` function because the data from subscriptions (such as who is logged in) will take a short while to arrive, by which time startup would have completed.

Use `Tracker.autorun()` instead:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    if(Meteor.userId()) {
        ///
    }
});
```

Be careful this will run whever the user logs in as well. To ensure it only runs once you could use a `Session` that could store how many times its run, and stop it if it runs more than once.

Comment: Calling `Meteor.userId()` inside `Deps.autorun` results with another error: `Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber`

Comment: Are you doing this on the server?. You can't get the user's Id anywhere unless a request from the client is made to the server (i.e a publish function, a method, or some call of some sort). Because there is no way to distinguish which user is logged in without some form of communication with the client so its not possible within in a `startup` & Deps.autorun only runs on the client

Comment: Yeah. I'm fu**g dumb. This meteor thing got me all decentralized a bit lol.

Comment: Lol well I wouldn't say that. It might be better to use a Meteor.call from the client instead within a Deps.autorun like above so as soon as theyre logged in something can happen on the server end

Answer (score 0):

The answer is clearly mentioned in the error message. By the way, you need to check whether logged in or not before trying to print.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (this.userId)
        console.log(this.userId);
});
```

Comment: well i tried `this.userId` but as a method the same way you would try `Meteor.userId()`. Anyways, seems to work so ty

Comment: Scratch that. It doesnt send any error but it doesn't wotk with logged in user either. `this.userId` is always `undefined`.